# Can Google Analytics be configured to merge keywords that differ only in capitalization / case sensitivity?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, keywords, reporting, case-sensitive

I'm looking at my company's paid keywords under Acquisition > Google Ads > Keywords in Analytics, and I notice that I have two separate results for my brand keyword, e.g.

**e**xample ... (not the real name)

widget a ...

**E**xample ...

etc ...

This isn't ideal. Can Google Analytics, at any level (Account, property, or this specific report) be configured to ignore capitalization and case sensitivity, so that mecanico, Mecanico, MECANICO etc. are treated as a single keyword? I know this can be done for URLs. Can it be done for keywords?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if your Google Ads URL's are tagged with UTM parameters. (Parameters can be either manually added or auto-tagged.) You also have to make sure you're using the "utm_term" parameter.

If the above is true for your campaigns, inside whichever Property you can go to your non-raw data View(s) > click on "Filters" > add a new Custom Filter > choose "Lowercase" > select "Campaign Term" in the Filter Field.

(More info here on [Google Analytics Filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en) and [UTM Parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en).)